# Image of $f$ comes arbitrarily close to every $c$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $p_1, p_2,\ldots,p_n$ are points on the compact Riemann surface $X$ and $Y:=X-\{p_1,.....,p_n\}$.   Suppose
$$f:Y→\mathbb{C}$$
is a non-constant holomorphic function. Show that the image of $f$ comes arbitrarily close to every $c$ in $\mathbb{C}$.$//$ Is this mean that, we have to show $f(Y)$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$? Then how can we proceed? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the image misses some ball $B(z,r)$. Then we consider the function $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z) - c}$. Then $g$ is non-constant and bounded by $\frac{1}{r}$, so we may extend it to obtain a non-constant holomorphic function on $X$, which is impossible.

Comment: Sir why this is impossible to extend on $X$? There is no given condition that $p_k\>'s$ are some type of singularities of $f$.

Comment: There are no non-constant holomorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface. And what I'm extending is $g$ instead of $f$, the point is that since $g$ is bounded on $Y$, the $p_k$ are removable singularities for it.

Comment: Thank you sir..

Comment: Thanks ! I find this beautiful solution, i was asking the same question.